# How do I write the result of tf.Data.dataset.take() using TFRecordWriter?

Tags: tensorflow, keras, tfrecord

I am attempting to read in a tfrecord file, shuffle and split it, and then save to two tfrecords so I can use the same validation data in multiple runs.

The problem I'm getting is that what I assumed would be a Dataset object is a TakeDataset object.

I'm on Ubuntu 16.04 and using Tensorflow 2.1.0.

The relevant code:

```
dataset = create_dataset(filenames_train, batch_size=25)

validation_dataset = dataset.take(8400)
training_dataset = dataset.skip(8400)

writer_valid = tf.data.experimental.TFRecordWriter("./Data/valid.tfrecord")
writer_valid.write(validation_dataset)
writer_train = tf.data.experimental.TFRecordWriter("./Data/train.tfrecord")
writer_train.write(training_dataset)
```

The output is:

```
...in <module>
    writer_valid.write(validation_dataset)
  File "/home/kyle/Desktop/learning/venv/lib/python3.5/site-packages/tensorflow_core/python/data/experimental/ops/writers.py", line 107, in write
    if not dataset_ops.get_structure(dataset).is_compatible_with(
AttributeError: 'tuple' object has no attribute 'is_compatible_with'
```

Comment: Hi @Kyle, can you please include the minimum reproducible code to demonstrate your problem? specifically the ```create_dataset``` function?

Answer (score 4):

It depends on what type of data your `tf.data.Dataset holds`, I have taken string data as example and given the method below, to complement the solution I have provided helper functions for other types of data as well.

In order to write data to `TFRecords`, we need to convert each data point to a byte-string and then write using `tf.io.TFRecordsWriter`.

Let's see how to achieve that.

First, let us define `tf.data.Dataset`

```
dataset = tf.data.Dataset.from_tensor_slices(["one","two","three","four"])
```

Now, this dataset has to be serialized .

```
def serialize_example(data):
  # feature = {
  #     'feature0': _int64_feature(feature0),
  #     'feature1': _float_feature(feature1),
  #     'feature2': _bytes_feature(feature2),
  #     'feature3': _bytes_feature(feature3),
  # }

  feature = {
    'feature': _bytes_feature(data)
  }
# Create a Features message using tf.train.Example.
  example_proto = tf.train.Example(features=tf.train.Features(feature=feature))
  return example_proto.SerializeToString()
```

I have commented for other types of feature since the feature I'm considering here is string. You can choose the type from the feature dictionary according to your data.

Providing all the functions for converting each feature in the data to `tf.train.Feature`.

```
def _bytes_feature(value):
    """Returns a bytes_list from a string / byte."""
    # If the value is an eager tensor BytesList won't unpack a string from an EagerTensor.
    if isinstance(value, type(tf.constant(0))):
        value = value.numpy() 
    return tf.train.Feature(bytes_list=tf.train.BytesList(value=[value]))

def _float_feature(value):
    """Returns a float_list from a float / double."""
    return tf.train.Feature(float_list=tf.train.FloatList(value=[value]))

def _int64_feature(value):
    """Returns an int64_list from a bool / enum / int / uint."""
    return tf.train.Feature(int64_list=tf.train.Int64List(value=[value]))
```

Now, we are all set to create TFRecord using `TFRecordWriter`.

```
file_path = 'data.tfrecords'
with tf.io.TFRecordWriter(file_path) as writer:
  for i in dataset.take(-1):

    serialized_example = serialize_example(i)    
    writer.write(serialized_example)
```

**Note:** dataset.take(-1) will take all the records present in your `tf.data.Dataset`

Now your TFRecord file is created.

```
file_paths = [file_path]
tfrecord_dataset = tf.data.TFRecordDataset(file_paths)
```

Now each data point in this dataset are simply the raw byte-strings as returned by serialize_example function. The following function reads a serialized_example and parse it using the feature description.

```
def read_tfrecord(serialized_example):
  # feature_description = {
  #       'feature0': tf.io.FixedLenFeature((), tf.int64),
  #       'feature1': tf.io.FixedLenFeature((), tf.float32),
  #       'feature2': tf.io.FixedLenFeature((), tf.string),
  #       'feature3': tf.io.FixedLenFeature((), tf.string),
  # } 

  feature_description = {
      'feature': tf.io.FixedLenFeature((), tf.string)
  }
  example = tf.io.parse_single_example(serialized_example, feature_description)

  feature = example['feature']

  return feature  

parsed_dataset = tfrecord_dataset.map(read_tfrecord)
```

**Result:**

```
for data in parsed_dataset.take(-1):
  print(data)  

tf.Tensor(b'one', shape=(), dtype=string)
tf.Tensor(b'two', shape=(), dtype=string)
tf.Tensor(b'three', shape=(), dtype=string)
tf.Tensor(b'four', shape=(), dtype=string)
```

If you are working with Images as data, you can follow [this beautiful post](https://towardsdatascience.com/working-with-tfrecords-and-tf-train-example-36d111b3ff4d) to achieve the same.

Comment: @Kyle - If the above answer helps to solve your issue, please accept and upvote the answer, Thank you!

Comment: Very thorough! Just want to point out that there is a library util to do this too, although it's not a lot of code honestly https://github.com/google/seqio/blob/main/seqio/utils.py#L168